# How to local forward multiple hops?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding, ssh-tunnel

I'm trying to access web server running on `serverB` and `port 10010` from `host machine (my PC)`. In short, the server is running on `serverB`'s `localhost:10010`.

To do that,

1. I have to local forward from `host machine (my PC)` to `serverA`'s `localhost` by using:

   `ssh -L 10010:localhost:10010 user@serverA`.
2. In addition, from `serverA`, I have to local forward to `serverB`'s `localhost` by using:

   `ssh -L 10010:localhost:1000 user@serverB`.

In general, this can be achieved by using the following command from `host machine (my PC)`:

`ssh -L 10010:localhost:10010 user@serverA ssh -L 10010:localhost:10010 user@serverB`.

How to do same thing by using ssh config (`~/.ssh/config`)?

Comment: By "same thing", do you mean the forwardings? or everything? In other words: do you want to connect like `ssh user@serverA ssh user@serverB`? or `ssh serverB`?

Answer (score 0):

All `ssh` command line arguments have corresponding config file equivalents.  In the case of `-L`, that is the same as `LocalForward` as a config file or `-o LocalForward=` command line option.

Suggest you look at the `ssh_config(5)` man page - for example:  https://manpages.org/ssh_config/5